# Ethereum storage - how does this cost happen?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

```
contract A { 
      
    uint x = 10;
    
    function test2() public {
        x = 0;
    }
          
}
```

I can see that:

- Transaction cost is 13204
- Execution cost is 5136

How can this be ? I calculate differently.

Those 3 are taken from white paper.

- Paid for every transaction - 21000
- Paid for an SSTORE operation when the storage value’s zeroness remains unchanged or
  is set to zero. - 5000
- Refund given (added into refund counter) when the storage value is set to zero from
  non-zero - 15000

So, 21000 + 5000 - 15000 = 11000. How did we get 13204 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a cap to the maximum refundable gas. Only half of the total used gas can be refunded. (*)

In the example at most you can refund (21000 + 5000) / 2 = 13000 gas.

So it will be at 21000 + 5000 - min(13000, 15000) = 26000 - 13000 = 13000. Very close to the measured amount.

(*) The exact details are in [Ethereum's Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) *Section 6.2 Execution.*

Comment: Hi Ismael @Ismael, I wanted to hear your opinion on this. Let's say the gas transaction needed is `21000+3+3+5000 = 26006`, but the refund of the operation is `15,000`. Now, we can't get 15,000, since it exceeds half the amount, so we get only `26003/2 = 13003` as refund. I know that this is because if we give 15,000 refund in this case, then miners will not be incentivized, but it really doesn't make sense. If we make the refund as `15,000`, miner still gts `26006-15000 = 11006` , So, he still gets money. why not incentivized ?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili I don't know why GasRefund <= GasUsed/2 is used. It seems easy to calculate though, but I don't know if there was another reason. Certainly allowing to refund GasUsed opens the possibility of DoS attacks.

Comment: The actual reason is that because if you dont , then miners are not incentivized. I couldnt understand though how it is related